# Is there any way to configure aws dynamoDB with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to laravel. I want to know the steps for configuring aws dynamoDB locally with laravel. Can anyone tell me the process?

Answer (score 0):

its simple friend

open **.env** file and config Your DB

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE= --Your DB name --
DB_USERNAME= -- Your User name --
DB_PASSWORD= -- Your Password---
```